# Difficulty finding the sum of a hyperbolic function.

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

Can someone please point out where I am (If I am) going wrong during the solution process of the following question:

I have been presented with the following :

$$4sinh(2ln(2))-cosh(ln2)$$

and told by my tutor the solution is 10. however I cannot obtain this value, the steps I take are as follows :

$$(4*(e^{ln(2)^2} - e^{-ln(2)^2}/2)) - (e^{ln(2)} + e^{-ln(2)}/2) $$

$$2e^{2ln(2)} - 2e^{-2ln(2)} - 0.5e^{ln(2)} + 0.5e^{-ln(2)} $$

$$8 - 0.5 - 1 + 0.25$$

$$6.75$$

For added clarity I will show a picture of notes I have regarding the question :
[image]

I would very much appreciate if someone can help me reach a solution as to why my answer differs from the tutors. Thank you.

Comment: but we get for $$2\ln(2)=\ln(2^2)$$

Comment: My calculator says $6.25$.  On the third line you forgot to negate the minus sign when you "took away" the parenthesis.

Comment: Ah yes i realise this now, thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer should be $6.25$.

\begin{align}
 & 4 \sinh (2 \ln 2) - \cosh(\ln2 ) \\
=& 2 \left(e^{2\ln2}-e^{-2\ln2} \right) - \frac{e^{\ln2}+e^{-\ln2}}{2}\\
=& 2(4-0.25)-\frac{2+0.5}{2}\\
=& 7.5-1.25 = 6.25.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, I will run this by my tutor so that he doesn't potentially mark my answer incorrect in an exam !

Answer (score 1):

You're correct:
$$\begin{align} 4\sinh{2\log{2}} - \cosh{\log{2}} &= \cosh{(\log{2})} \left( 8\sinh{(\log{2})}-1 \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(2+1/2)(4 \cdot 2 - 4 \cdot 1/2-1) \\
&= \frac{5}{4}(8-2-1) \\ &= \frac{25}{4} \end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, I thought my answer was more feasible than 10. Will run this by my tutor in the morning :)